# Disable / Enable all the labels and textFields and even some buttons until the user click a checkBox

Tags: button, javafx, label, textfield, handle

### Disable/Enable

These details are about my VBox:

1: a checkBox

2: a label and own textField

3: a button

so I want to **disable** number 2 and number 3 **until** **user** **click** on its checkBox.

I override a handle method as see in below:

```
sectionDisable.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            myLabel.setDisable(!myField.isDisable());
            myField.setDisable(!myField.isDisable());
            mybutton.setDisable(!mybutton.isDisable());
        }
    });
```

okay. but as I told to y'all I want these options be disable at first, I tried like this:

```
            myLabel.setDisable(true);
            myField.setDisable(true);
            mybutton.setDisable(true);
```

but it's not working as I want! and they're disable all the time, no consider to checkBox!

After Enable them, if user click on checkBox then they Disable again.

The problem is I don't know how can set disable'em for the first time.

Comment: Can you post a [mre]: the code should basically work, so if it's not working, there's something wrong we can't see. Note that you do have a copy-and-paste error in your handler, though it should still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay!

It's work good now! I changed my view, so I use setSelected(); for my checkBox

and now there's no need to this code:

```
myLabel.setDisable(true);
myField.setDisable(true);
mybutton.setDisable(true);
```

After:

[image]

Before:
[image]

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Just: could you please remove all the shouting (aka: unnecessary bolded text) and horizontal lines from both answer and question, they make them near-to unreadable ..

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your controls to the CheckBox by using disableProperty().

---

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML public Label myLabel;
    @FXML public TextField myTextField;
    @FXML public Button myButton;
    @FXML public CheckBox myCheckbox;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)  {

        myCheckbox.setSelected(true);

        myLabel.disableProperty().bind(myCheckbox.selectedProperty());
        myTextField.disableProperty().bind(myCheckbox.selectedProperty());
        myButton.disableProperty().bind(myCheckbox.selectedProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow [java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)